# Create a printable image from an UV

Tags: uv, image

After reading [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26268/qr-code-in-shopping-cart-handle), I wanted to do something similar in Blender. I created a cylinder and mapped an image using UV Project with the camera. Now I had something that looked like this: [image: Cylinder with QR code.]

This is where I got stuck. I need some way to create an image that I could print from my printer, that when wrapped around a cylinder looked like this. The approach I've tried is transforming the cylinder into a plane, but there doesn't seem to be a good way to do this. [Here's the .blend](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=37907912948217631468)

Comment: please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to share blend files, your link is connected to a nasty ad-network

Comment: did you try : Unwrap -> Project from View?